# When to use vs when to avoid use of useState in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Let's Imainge there are two in put boxes on the screen. When two numbers are provided as input, our react application automatically displays a result calculated using **calculateResult** function.

The value of each of the box is stored in states **num1** and **num2** respectively. **setNum1** and **setNum2** are used to set these states.

Which of the following is a better approach of displaying the result on change of the num1 or num2.

Approach 1: using useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    setResult(calculateResult(num1, num2));
}, [num1, num2])

const onChangeNum1 = (e) => {
    setNum1(e.target.value);
}
const onChangeNum2 = (e) => {
    setNum2(e.target.value);
}
<input onChange={onChangeNum1}/>
<input onChange={onChangeNum2}/>
```

Approach 2: Changing result state inside onChange Function

```
const onChangeNum1 = (e) => {
    setNum1(e.target.value);
    setResult(calculateResult(e.target.value, num2));
}
const onChangeNum2 = (e) => {
    setNum2(e.target.value);
    setResult(calculateResult(num1, e.target.value));
}
<input onChange={onChangeNum1}/>
<input onChange={onChangeNum2}/>
```

Both of these approaches work fine. Therefore It would be really helpful if someone could explain the difference in the efficiency of these approaches, Which one should be used when ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these is a good approach, since the result shouldn't be state at all, since it's directly derived from other state and not editable by the user.

IOW, just

- `const result = calculateResult(num1, num2);`,
- or if it's heavier to compute, `const result = React.useMemo(() => calculateResult(num1, num2), [num1, num2]);`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AKX [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77149985/5157454), you don't even need 2 states. You can use one (an object) state to hold the numbers, and a single function to update it:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const calcProduct = (n1, n2) => n1 * n2;

const Demo = () => {
  const [nums, setNums] = useState({ n1: 0, n2: 0 });

  const onChangeNum = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setNums(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  }
  
  const product = calcProduct(nums.n1, nums.n2);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(nums)
        .map(([key, val]) => (
          <input key={key} name={key} value={val} onChange={onChangeNum}/>
        ))
      }
      
      <div>product: {product}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(demo)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```